# Unable to install gulp globally - multiple warnings in terminal

Tags: terminal, npm, gulp

I'm having trouble downloading gulp. I already have node and npm installed, but when I try to download gulp I get a warning, and the command "grunt" doesn't work. 
[sudo npm install -g gulp (screenshot of terminal)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjeXa.png)

I also tried another variation in the terminal: [sudo npm install --global gulp-cli (screenshot of terminal)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fnn3v.png)
This ran what looks like pretty much the same code but with less warnings - however, it still doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Also, I'm not sure if I've successfully downloaded gulp locally. Have I downloaded it if there's a folder called "node_modules", with "bootstrap-sass", "gulp", "gulp-install" and "laravel-elixir" inside it? (It's inside a Laravel project btw)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [getting started (and installing gulp globally)](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md), specifically:

> If you have previously installed a version of gulp globally, please run `npm rm --global gulp` to make sure your old version doesn't collide with gulp-cli.
>   `$ npm install --global gulp-cli`

Basically, it looks like you should uninstall `gulp` globally and replace it with `gulp-cli`, and then make sure to install gulp locally with `npm install --save-dev gulp` in your project.

> Have I downloaded it if there's a folder called "node_modules", with "bootstrap-sass", "gulp" [...] ?

Yes, if `gulp` exists in `node_modules` in your project, you've installed it locally.

Comment: When I run "npm install --global gulp -cli" (after running "npm rm --global gulp") I get this error: https://gyazo.com/63c1adb271d0dd5c90a47f6129ef15ab 

Do you have any idea why it isn't working?